# How to call PHP CLI from C?

Tags: c, linux, php

I'm writing an application that sends requests to the PHP CLI. However, as i try to run the application, php complains it can't find the script to run.

Here's the relevant code:

```
char *params[] = {
    "/usr/bin/php",
    "-f /var/www/test/php/tracker/gps-upload-sh.php",
    imei,
    rmc,
    (char *) 0
};
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
pid_t pID = fork();
if (pID == 0) {
    if(execv("/usr/bin/php", params) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to call php.");
        _exit(1);
    }
    _exit(0);
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./socket
Could not open input file:  /var/www/test/php/tracker/gps-upload-sh.php
^C
```

File:

```
$ ls -l /var/www/test/php/tracker/gps-upload-sh.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 onik onik 6707 2012-03-09 16:00 /var/www/test/php/tracker/gps-upload-sh.php
```

Run directly (where REQUIRED_PARAMS are the same as the ones passed from the execv):

```
$ php -f /var/www/test/php/tracker/gps-upload-sh.php [REQUIRED_PARAMS]
OK
```

What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try separating the `-f` and the path into separate parameters:

```
char *params[] = {
    "/usr/bin/php",
    "-f",
    "/var/www/test/php/tracker/gps-upload-sh.php",
    imei,
    rmc,
    (char *) 0
};
```

(This is what your shell does with you put a space between the two.)

---

Alternatively, remove the space between `-f` and the path:

```
char *params[] = {
    "/usr/bin/php",
    "-f/var/www/test/php/tracker/gps-upload-sh.php",
    imei,
    rmc,
    (char *) 0
};
```

Comment: Thanks, the first suggestion worked! I suspected it was something really simple, completely missed that :)